# Why is Azure SQL database "force plan" automatic tuning disabled by the system?

Tags: azure-sql-database, query-optimization, sql-query-store, auto-tuning

I have set the the "desired state" to ON for the three automatic tuning options for my Azure SQL database (i.e. force plan, create index, drop index).

The database compatibility level is 150 and the Query Store operation mode is "read write".

However, the **force plan** setting remains at OFF, with the message "disabled by system". This is confirmed by querying `sys.database_automatic_tuning_options`.

I'm keen to take advantage of the automated plan forcing. What could be causing this, and is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I could find this documented in the official MS doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automatic-tuning-enable#automated-recommendation-management-is-disabled)

> #### Automated recommendation management is disabled
>
> In case of error messages that automated recommendation management has
> been disabled, or simply ***disabled by system***, the most common causes
> are:
>
> - Query Store is not enabled, or
> - Query Store is in read-only mode for a specified database, or
> - Query Store stopped running because it used the allocated storage space.
>
> The following steps can be considered to rectify this issue:
>
> - Clean up the Query Store, or modify the data retention period to "auto" by using T-SQL. See how to [configure recommended retention and
>   capture policy for Query
>   Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use#recommended-retention-and-capture-policy).
> - Use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and follow these steps:
>
>   - Connect to the Azure SQL Database
>   - Right click on the database
>   - Go to Properties and click on Query Store
>   - Change the Operation Mode to Read-Write
>   - Change the Store Capture Mode to Auto
>   - Change the Size Based Cleanup Mode to Auto

Comment: Thanks for this. In fact, the query store is enabled and in read-write state, as noted in the question. It hasn't filled the storage space. Capture mode and cleanup mode are both set to Auto.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following excerpt from a Microsoft article about the subject.

> Please note that although you might have one of the auto tuning
> options set to ON, the system might decide to temporarily disable
> automatic tuning if it deems necessary to protect the workload
> performance. It also could be that if the Query Store is not enabled
> on a database, or if it is in a read-only state, this will also render
> automatic tuning as temporarily disabled. In this case, view of the
> current state will indicate “Disabled by the system” and the value of
> the column actual_state will be 0.

The first line of the excerpt mentions that the system may decide to temporarily disable automatic tuning options to protect the workload performance. Read the complete article **[here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automatic-tuning-introduces-automatic-plan-correction-and-t-sql-management/#:%7E:text=Automatic%20plan%20correction%2C%20feature%20introduced%20in%20SQL%20Server,positive%20performance%20gain%20for%20workloads%20running%20on%20Azure.)**.

Comment: Thank you, that was an interesting article. Unfortunately, it just restates the issue that the setting is "disabled by system", but provides no solution. As noted in the question, query store is in read-write state.

Comment: It says is temporary. The system will enabled it when it considers the features won't affect the workload of the database. Glad you like the article.